# How to insert multiple rows with same id in java & mysql

Tags: java, mysql

```
public boolean saveScore1(Score obj) {
    boolean returnValue = false;
    String sql = "insert into score(e_id,u_id,u_score,y_id,b_id) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        Connection connection = DBConnectionHandler.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, obj.getEId());
        ps.setInt(2, obj.getUId());
        ps.setString(3, obj.getUScore());
        ps.setInt(4, obj.getYId());
        ps.setInt(5, obj.getBId());

        int i = ps.executeUpdate();

        if (i > 0) {
            returnValue = true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Here are the *three table* i'm using

**Examtable:** `e_id integer(auto increment) pk,e_name varchar`

**UserTable:** `u_id integer(auto increment)pk,u_name varchar`

**ScoreTable:** `s_id integer(auto increment)pk ,u_id integer fk, e_id integer fk, u_score`

---

I want to send multiple data to score table **at a time** with one sql query for same u_id but different e_id, beacuse e_id will contains different value like B.B.A,M.B.A, B.sc, M.sc etc. So one user can have different exam pass. 
I'm using above java code to insert but i just take the last value from front-end jsf form. 
How can i send multiple rows for same u_id with different e_id at a time.

Comment: "but i just take the last value from front-end jsf form" - seems like an issue on the other side of the code and not on the Java or MySQL end. Pls post the necessary relevant front end code also.

Comment: some one please teach the teachers to stress that properly formatting your code is paramount to be a professional programmer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't insert data with a SQL query. A query is a `SELECT` statement.

Using JDBC, you can *batch* multiple insert statements, such that number of round trips to the database are reduced (for performance). Functionally, it is the same as inserting one row at a time.

Since you are inserting multiple rows, you probably want all to succeed, or all to fail, so you need to do your own `commit` or `rollback`.

Of course, since to *do* want to insert multiple score rows, your method should take a `List<Score>`.

```
public boolean saveScores(List<Score> scores) {
    String sql = "insert into score(e_id,u_id,u_score,y_id,b_id) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    try (Connection connection = DBConnectionHandler.getConnection()) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                for (Score score : scores) {
                    ps.setInt   (1, score.getEId());
                    ps.setInt   (2, score.getUId());
                    ps.setString(3, score.getUScore());
                    ps.setInt   (4, score.getYId());
                    ps.setInt   (5, score.getBId());
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
            connection.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            connection.rollback();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have used your suggested code in ResImpleDao folder and call this from Controller like : public boolean insertScore(){ return resImple.saveScoresList((List<Score>) sc)}; Here sc is object for Score Class which has been Declared in this Controller Class.  and then I  write

Comment: Class which has been Declared in this Controller Class.  and then I  write public void doInsert(){ boolean isSuccess =insertReg(); if(isSuccess) doSetuserID(); insertScore(); } and i set doInsert() method in jsf commandbutton for insert.  but exception is that Score can't be cast to java.util.list

Comment: Of course you can't cast a `Score` to a `List<Score>`. You have to create a list, e.g. `ArrayList`, and add multiple `Score` objects to it. The entire point is that to insert multiple Score rows into the database, you'd need multiple Score objects in memory, with the values for each Score row to create.